# My CSS file won’t load. I try to search the internet but didn’t found a solution. can you assist me?

Tags: css, django, django-models, django-static

Hi for some reason my CSS file won’t load.
I try to search the internet but didn’t found a solution.
can you assist me ? [My settings code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m1vr3.png)

I've tried every possible solution on the internet, but it's of no use.

Comment: could you post actual code rather than a screenshot?

Comment: STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILE_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static")
]

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR,'assets')

Comment: [How to put code in StackOverflow questions](https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/5-ways-to-embed-code-in-stack-overflow-8d9f38edf02c)  You might want to add the html template where you link to the css, and perhaps your urls.py as well.

Comment: I'm learning django on my own. this is my first project. Do you mind explaining little bit clearly.

Comment: [Cannot connect .js files with html files in django](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74619261/cannot-connect-js-files-with-html-files-in-django/74620638#74620638). Check out my answer